# How to pass an existing collection to a controller in order to render a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search results page that lists found items.  On that list I have a button that I want to use to show thumbnails of the results.

I have the controller method that shows the searched images:

```
def search
    @search_criteria = params[:search]
    @novels = Novel.where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{@search_criteria.downcase}%")
    @novels.sort! { |a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase }

    @searched_illustrations = Illustration.where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{@search_criteria.downcase}%")
    @tagged_illustrations = Illustration.tagged_with([@search_criteria], :any => true, :wild => true)
    @illustrations = @searched_illustrations + @tagged_illustrations
    @illustrations.uniq!
    @illustrations.sort! { |a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase }

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html #search_results.html.erb
 end
end
```

Here is the code I have attached to the button on the view that shows the search results:

```
<%= link_to "Show", illustration, :class => "btn btn-custom-primary btn-mini", :style => "float:right;" %>
```

Here is the controller method I have to display the thumbnails:

```
def show_illustrations
    @illustrations = params[:illustrations]

    @illustrations = Kaminari.paginate_array(@illustrations).page(params[:page]).per(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #search_results.html.erb
    end
  end
```

I'm getting this error, that leads me to believe I'm getting an array of illustration ids as params[illustrations]:

```
undefined method `aws_image_thumbnail_url' for "2":String
```

Answer (score 0):

`link_to("Show", object)` will normally produce a URL like `/illustrations/:id`. A show route. You're trying to render a collection.

Generally, I think you're trying to just show your search results in a different way, no? At least that's what I gather from your examples. If that's the case, render a different view.

```
def search 
  # search stuff... (you should try ElasticSearch/Tire)
  #
  # Now, use a different template if the 'thumbs' param is present
  return render :search_thumbs unless params[:thumbs].nil?
end
```

In the view:

```
= link_to "View Thumbs", search_path(search: params[:search], thumbs: true)
```